# Lastrow larger than 3000 produces error

Tags: excel, vba

The code below works just fine with any the LastRow value less than 3000 (approx) but it fails when I change the value to a higher number. I need the LastRow value to be around 100000

When I change the counter to a higher value I get

> error 1004 (Application or object define error)

Any reason?

```
Sub InsertRow()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Col = "A"
        StartRow = 1

        LastRow = 10000
        Worksheets("Output").Activate


        With Worksheets("Output")
           For R = LastRow To StartRow Step -1
                If Cells(R, Col) = 1 Then
                    Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Cells(R, 1) = 0
                    Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R + 1, 2)

            Next R
        End With
        Range("A1").Activate
        Dim LR As Long, LC As Long
        LR = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row
        LC = ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column

        Worksheets("Output").Range("A1", Cells(LR, LC)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Trans").Range("A1")


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not calculate the lastrow instead? It would be more reliable.

Comment: In which line you get the error?

Comment: In my code, I actually calculated the last Row, it doesnt work as the number is high. So I hard coded it to 1000, it works. If I change it to 10000, it throws an error. Is this a memory issue?

Comment: Just because you use `With Worksheets("Output")` it doesn't automatically mean that e.g. `Cells` refers to cells in that worksheet. Similarly for `Range`. You would need to use `.Cells` (note the dot). If you want to rely on activating the sheet instead (as you seem to do), just drop the `With` altogether.

Comment: Open Task Manager and monitor your RAM

Comment: Whatever worksheet is active probably has an `#N/A` error value  (or whatever other worksheet error) at a row number somewhere around 3000. Heed @JohnColeman's advice and qualify all `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows` and `Columns` members calls with the proper `Worksheet` object you mean to be working with. Oh look, `Worksheets("Output").Activate`! Sloppy work-around for implicit `ActiveSheet` references... don't do that.

Comment: @goog: Best you edit your answer to explain the business function that this code performs.

Comment: Also, won't `.cells(R, "A")` provoque failure ? I believe the cells coordinate are meant to be numeric values.

Comment: @MrDogme,  run this in the immediate window and look at the active worksheet `cells(2,"D").select`